# I have asked for your for my spider scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I try to extract the product from e- commerce

Crawl the site and has passed each product to extract title information , description, image and declensions if possible .

But my spider does not work.

```
import smtplib
import urlparse

from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from w3lib.html import replace_escape_chars, remove_tags
from scrapy.loader.processors import Compose, MapCompose

from emmiScraper.items import EmmiscraperItem


class EmmiSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'emi'
    allowed_domains = ['adns-grossiste.fr']
    start_urls = ['http://adns-grossiste.fr/95-joyetech']


    rules = (
         Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=()),   callback="parse", follow= True),
)

    def parse(self, response):
        """Yields url for every item currently available on the site, and
            transports every product name to parse_item method.

         @url http://emmi.rs/konfigurator /proizvodi.10.html?advanced_search=1&productTitle=&x=0&y=0
    @scrapes urls products

    """
    urls = response.xpath('//*[@id="center_column"]/ul/li/div/div[2]  /h5/a/@href').extract()
    products = response.xpath('//*[@id="center_column"]/ul/li/div/div[2]/h5/a/text()').extract()

    for url, product in zip(urls, products):
        yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url),
                      callback=self.parse_item,
                      meta={'product': product}
                      )

def parse_item(self, response):
         """Returns fields: url_of_item, product, img_url, description,   and   price."""

    l = ItemLoader(item=EmmiscraperItem(), response=response)
    l.default_output_processor = MapCompose(lambda v: v.strip(), replace_escape_chars)

    l.add_value('url_of_item', response.url)
    l.add_value('product', response.meta['product'])
    l.add_xpath('img_url', '//*[@id="bigpic"]/@src')
    l.add_xpath('description', '//*[@id="short_description_content"]/p[1]/span/text()')
    l.add_xpath('price', '//*[@id="our_price_display"]/text()')

    return l.load_item()
```

Comment: *"... my spider does not work ..."* - please be more specific what your problem is.

Comment: Thank you for your reply
the script worked well for scraping part but I added rules to be able to crawl all the site but since it function more.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be really a scrapy FAQ:

There is a Warning box in the [CrawlSpider documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules). It says:

> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since
>   the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic.
>   So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer
>   work. Your code does probably not work as expected because you do use
>   parse as callback.

Your code does probably not work as expected because you do use parse as callback.